# Is there a take-all keyboard shortcut in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In Fallout 3 you can hold the use key to just pick up all items on an enemy, container, et cetera. Does Deus EX: HR have a similar keyboard shortcut, or do I need to press the "take all" button with the mouse in order to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are in the inspect items view (tap <kbd>E</kbd> while looking at a body/corpse) pressing <kbd>E</kbd> again will take all the items that body/corpse has on them.

Comment: Assuming all the items will fit in your inventory however.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically choose **not** to or have a full/near full inventory you *will* automatically take all loot that in in a container/on a body.

Tap the <kbd>Use</kbd> button to open the looting screen, then tap <kbd>Use</kbd> again to close and take what you can.